# Editing Date Time Member Variables with a DropDownListFor doesn't save

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

So, I am trying to create a `DropDownList` that will edit the various member variables the `DateTime` class has (which I have an instance of in my model), such as Day, Month, and Year. However, when an item is selected in the `DropDownList` and the `Save` input button is clicked, the data does not save. All other edited pieces of data will be changed and saved, but the `DateTime` field will just not update. I'd rather not make a new model just for my Dates, but it can be done. I can create the `SelectList`, I do so in an `HTML Helper`, shown below:

```
namespace ErrorReport.Helpers
{
public class DateList
{
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DayList
    {
        get
        {
            var days = new List<SelectListItem>();
            for (int i = 1; i < 32; i++)
            {
                days.Add(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = i.ToString(),
                    Text = i.ToString()
                });
            }
            return days;
        }
    }
```

There's obviously two more Lists that get made, one for Year and one for Month (I'm not bothering with hours, minutes, or seconds), didn't show them since the code is identical. In my `View`, my editor code looks like the below, and the variable I want to change is `CmpD` (of `DateTime` class):

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" 
        type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Edit Report: "@Model.Title"</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReportId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SbmD)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserName)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CmpD)

    ...irrelevant editor code...

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CmpD, "Estimated Completion Date:")
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">  

        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CmpD.Month, DateList.MonthList)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CmpD.Day, DateList.DayList)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CmpD.Year, DateList.YearList)

        //@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CmpD.Month)
        //Above line was commented out
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

I did have validation in place for `CmpD's` member variables earlier (only the ones I wanted to change), commented them out because they kept throwing validation errors for every possible `SelectList` choice (marked in above code). I didn't put arguments in the `BeginForm` function because they caused save problems with saving the other data. I also added the `HiddenFor` field for `CmpD` (which is my `DateTime`) to get everything to save properly, since without that line of code the return controller did not recognize the `Model as valid` and didn't save it. I tried adding a `HiddenFor` field for **every member variable** in the `DateTime` class I am not using, and I still get Validation errors if I remove the `HiddenFor(model => model.CmpD)`, even with other `Hidden Fields` present. I have also tried to make a list this way:

```
    public static IEnumerable<int> YearList
    {
        get
        {
            var years = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                years.Add(i);
            }
            return years.AsEnumerable();
        }
    }
```

However, this prevents the `Html.DropDownListFor` function from working at all, it apparently has to use `SelectList items`. I have noticed that only `strings` can be `SelectList items`, and that the `DateTime` member variables are `ints`. Is that causing the problem? Because I don't see where they are recasted to `ints` and cannot figure out how I would do that. Basically, how do I edit `DateTime member variables` in a `DropDownList`?

Also: Is this too much inline code? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DateTime properties (Day, Month, etc.) are all read-only. Hence, it is not possible to set them on a DateTime instance.
You would need settable int properties in your model to be able to update the values from the drop-downs. Then you can construct a DateTime from those values later. I would probably create a separate model class just for this purpose and implement the date editor as separate editor template or partial view that handles all the details (to keep your code clean).

Comment: Ok, so I tried making a custom class. In this class there are 3 ints that will hold my Day, Month, and Year. If I implement this editor in a partial View and call it with: `@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/DatesModel.cshtml", Model.TempDate)`, the values will not save over. Here TempDate is my instance of the Model with the 3 ints (called DatesModel) in my main Model. I know the partial view is being called, because it will render the drop down boxes and any text boxes created with the EditorFor function. It just won't save the values. If I implement it in the edit view, it works.

Comment: Regardless of the above comment, your response greatly helped. It wasn't what I wanted to hear, but it was useful and usable. If you know why the error in my above comment is happening, that would be great. Thanks though!

Comment: Does all your properties (the int properties and the TempDate) have public setters?

Comment: Yea, I'm pretty sure they all do unless I'm grossly misunderstanding you. You are asking about the lines `public int Day { get; set; }` right? If so, every member variable in my TempDate Model has a public getter/setter, and the TempDate member variable in my main Model has one too.